# If Unity will be touch friendly, will window buttons become easier to touch?

Tags: unity, multi-touch

Some people say that Unity is touch friendly and I even saw a video of an Ubuntu developer showing it off on a Dell touch screen.

It looks touch friendly and all but the window buttons still look too tiny to be touch friendly. There could be a gesture or something to close the windows easily, but not everyone will know about them and will aim at the little buttons.

Answer (score 7):

Gestures will be the easiest method for closing windows in touch environment. There have been several ideas discussing how to improve the window button in a touch environment, however no firm decisions have been made. Ideas range from making the buttons grow bigger on tap (so you have a bigger hit area) to having just plain ol huge buttons.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I was Thinking about the "tab to make buttons larger" idea. It makes perfect sense to me.